# Free reporting tools for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I'm looking free reporting tools like SharpShooter.
I use VS2008, if reporting tools can work with asp.net it would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there should be CrystalReports bundeled with VS2008. Or you should be able to use [Microsoft Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms252708%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Here is a [sample-walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251686.aspx) from MSDN

Comment: could you prompt some tutorial with Microsoft Reporting?

Comment: All he would do is google for it - which you can do yourself, no?

Comment: yep - of course adding some googled link to a tuturial might improve the answer so...

Answer (score 0):

don't miss to take a look into [List&Label Free Edition](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/free-edition). It has an interesting [approach](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/good-reasons-to-choose-reporting-tool-List-Label) of reporting and is - in my experience - more helpful in a lot of cases. They announced a [new version](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label-new-version) in some weeks which will be even better for use with ASP.NET. Plenty of coding examples are included